# Line not visible in zedgraph - How to create overlapping filled line graphs using zedgraph such that all the curves and their fills are visible?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am creating a line graph using zedgraph which contains multiple lines and all of them are filled with labels displaying the data points. There are times when one of the lines is not visible at all but only the data point labels for that line are visible. I think this happens when the data is such that one line completely envelopes the other in terms of area covered and the order of rendering for the lines is such that the inner line is rendered before the container line. This I think is making the inner line invisible except for its data point.

So my question is:

- How using zedgraph can I ensure that all portions of the filled curves along with their lines are rendered properly irrespective of their filled overlapping areas being subsets of each other and the order in which the curves are rendered?
- How using zedgrapgh can I force the overlapping portions of the curves to display a fill color that is a resultant of the individual fill colors for the curves like in the chart image I found on google charts demo page below?

[image: Overlapping area fill color is different than individual curve fill colors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!! - The only thing to do was add the alpha channel transparency to my line curve fills and everything else gets sorted automatically. Hope this helps someone.